# jquery mobile ui-select text too long for iphone

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, select, ellipsis

Jquery mobile application. I have a select in a table cell. the select of `United States Minor Outlying Islands` is too wide for iphone 4/5/6, and the table is stretched to fit its content and clipped by screen. How to display the selection text as ellipsis like `United States Minor ...` so that it will fit in the screen width.

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>

<div class="ui-select">

  <div class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <span class="ui-select-one-menu">United States Minor Outlying Islands</span>

    <select name="country" class="ui-select-one-menu" size="1"> 

       <option value="GS">South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands</option>
       <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
       <option value="US">United States</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The style from jquery-mobile.css

```
.ui-select .ui-btn > span:not(.ui-li-count) {
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The style seems to intend for the purpose(text-overflow: ellipsis), but it did not work.

Thanks for help.

------------ EDIT ---------------

After setting table-layout to fixed as suggested,

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

table columns overlap each other in jquery-mobile environment.

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" 
       class="ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-columntoggle"> 
   ... 
</table>
```

The computed table css seems normal

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 2px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 2px;
border-bottom-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
clear: both;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: table;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 1012px;
line-height: 18.2000007629395px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
table-layout: fixed;
text-shadow: rgb(243, 243, 243) 0px 1px 0px;
width: 264px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `table-layout: fixed` on your table. This keeps the table width from expanding beyond its set width and therefore the column contents will shrink/grow with the page size.

```
<table id="theTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="country" class="ui-select-one-menu" size="1">
                <option value="GS">South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands</option>
                <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                <option value="US">United States</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

#theTable{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6qnLrhyj/3/)**

Fixed table layout docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

Comment: After setting table-layout to fixed, columns overlap each other in jquery-mobile environment.
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-columntoggle"> ... </table>

Comment: @Dave, you did not mention you were using a jQM table, I thought you were just positioning controls.  Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6qnLrhyj/5/ it seems to work fine with a jQM table and multiple columns...

Comment: Thanks. It works. The cons about fixed layout is that all columns are assigned the same width by default. The auto layout is good if we can limit the table width to view port width somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-select .ui-btn > span:not(.ui-li-count) {
  overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

}

.ui-select-one-menu {
    width:200px;
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/6qnLrhyj/1/)

**OR**

This is using `Jquery`

```
var maxLength = 15;
$('.ui-select-one-menu > option').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        return text.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';  
    }
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/6qnLrhyj/2/)

Comment: setting width to a fixed length is not responsive to wide screen though. Thanks.